# r.watershed stream/rivers pixel size

Tags: grass-gis, stream, r.watershed

I am using r.watershed to get a stream map (which I assume is rivers). However the output rivers is always 1 pixel wide. I would've assumed that if I run this on say Iraq I would see the Tigris and Euphrates stand out / be abit larger.

Is there a way to tweak r.watershed to do this or is there another GRASS tool for this?

I am running on SRTM elevation maps if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you draw the stream size based on the flow accumulation value?

Comment: flow accumulation value - is that essentially river size?
do I get that from the accumulation output from r.watershed?

Comment: I think you are confusing between geomorphology structures, and water flow.  The `r.watershed` module does not know anything about water, rather it calculates streamlines based **only** on topography. You will get stream lines in the desert regions of Iraq, for example, where there are no flowing rivers at all.

Comment: And like @Micha, I'd add that river size is a relative concept, particularly in regions where rainfalls are episodic. The suggestion to use accumulation values will show the growing size of the bassin, not the actual flow. So it's just a proxy...

Comment: @Micha is there a module to get me the rivers?

Comment: Often satellite imagery is used to produce a land cover classification. This procedure can (usually) separate out water surfaces from vegetation, urban areas, etc. So that's a reasonable approach to "get the rivers". Search for "supervised classification"